# SSH tunnel behind Squid proxy server

Tags: ssh, proxy, vpn, squid, tunnel

How can I configure squid server on my local machine to redirect traffic to SSH tunnel created with Putty?

That's my goal:

**webBrowser--->Squid--->SSHTunnel--->remoteServer--->anything**

Comment: See if you could move the Squid server to 'remote server'. That is a easy problem to solve. If you have to keep Squid locally, then explore VPN based solutions.